# overwritng array elements react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After adding element to array, state overwrite this array and I have doubled all elements but the added one. I tried `setArray([])` before getting this array from database, but it didn't work..

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {

    setLoading(true)
    const objectRef = firebase.firestore().collection('obiekt').doc(object.id)

    let startDay = new Date(props.date);
    let endDay = new Date(props.date);

    startDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    endDay.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

    let datesArray = [];

    firebase.firestore().collection("wydarzenie")
        .where('obiekt', '==', objectRef)
        .where('data_rozpoczecia', '>=', startDay)
        .where('data_rozpoczecia', '<=', endDay)
        .orderBy('data_rozpoczecia')
        .onSnapshot(resp => {
            resp.docs.map(el => {
                datesArray.push({
                    ...el.data(),
                    id: el.id
                })
            })
            setLoading(false)
            setArray(datesArray)
            console.log(datesArray)
        })
}, [])
```

[..]

```
{array && array.map(hour => {
            return (
                <div className={styles.CalendarInfoHour} key={hour.id}>
                    {moment(hour.data_rozpoczecia.toDate()).locale('pl').format('LT')}-
                    {moment(hour.data_zakonczenia.toDate()).locale('pl').format('LT')} Zajęte
                </div>
            )
        })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want but if you are overwriting the previous array in state and you want to avoid that, do this:

`setArray([...array, newElementToAddToArray])`

instead of doing all this:

```
let datesArray = [];

resp.docs.map(el => {
   datesArray.push({
     ...el.data(),
     id: el.id
   })
})
```

do this:

```
resp.docs.map(el => {
   setArray({
     ...el.data(),
     id: el.id
   })
})
```

Comment: I want to replace old array with new one.

Comment: then just `setArray(newArray)` will work. what error are you getting?

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Had to move     `let datesArray = [];` inside `onSnapshot()` function.